# Setting HTML table column widths does not take effect

Tags: html, css

I have some tables that insist the columns should be the same width, how do I specify them?

to be clear, I want the left most column to narrow so that the other headers will fit on one line

Code sample

```
<div>
    <table style="width:610px;border-style:inset; border:1px; border-color:#000000; padding:3px;">
    <tr class="propGridHeader">
        <td style="width:150px!important;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;text-align:left;">Records: <asp:Label ID="lblHourCount" runat="server" /></td>
        <td style="width:153.3px;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;text-align:center;">Fixed Price</td>
        <td style="width:153.3px;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;text-align:center;">Liquidated Heat Rate</td>
        <td style="width:153.3px;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;text-align:center;">Liquidated Spark Spread</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:150px!important;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;" class="propDarkGrid">Average</td>
        <td style="width:153.3px;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;text-align:right;" class="propLightGrid"><asp:Label id="lblHourAvgFP" runat="server" /></td>
        <td style="width:153.3px;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;text-align:right;" class="propLightGrid"><asp:Label id="lblHourAvgHR" runat="server" /></td>
        <td style="width:153.3px;border:1px;border-style:inset;border-color:#000000;text-align:right;" class="propLightGrid"><asp:Label id="lblHourAvgSS" runat="server"  /></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use decimals in pixels. Just use `style="width:153px;border:1px`

[image]

Comment: fixed the decimals, still seems the columns are auto width

Comment: ie10 is the main one to be checked in chrome, ff and safari later

Answer (score 0):

You can't define td width with decimals, at least that you want to define it as em, so it would be this way:

For example:
width:5.5em;

em is mostly use is responsive web design. If you do not require to use responsive design so I recommend you to get rid of decimals and keep using px, like this:

For example:
width:153px;

Regards,